# Server responds with HTTP error 400 ("bad request") in a multipart request

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, http, web-services

I have a problem with a 3rd party application and my WCF web service that always returns a HTTP 400 ("bad request") error when connecting with the 3rd party application. The WebService is implemented via .NET, runs on MS Windows Server 2012-R2 and IIS8 and exposes an interoperable WSDL interface to connect to. The service itself is working pretty fine. I think the problem is more server- than service-related.

The WebService uses MTOM message encoding because of large result sets and on HTTP level this is realized via multipart HTTP messages. Basically the client send the headers first with a "Expect: 100-continue" field and an indentifier, the server acknowledges and then the client sends the rest. When using WCFTestClient from Microsoft, everythings works fine.

[image: Working example with WCFTestClient.exe and WebService]

The developer of the 3rd party app says his app sends header and body at the same time which may cause the server to respond with a bad request.

[image: Invalid example with 3rd party app and WebService]

He suggested to configure the server to accept header and body at the same time. I spent some time searching but I think I might have problems to describe the problem in short words. I have no idea where to find such a setting. Does anyone know more about this situation?